# Extract URI suffix as method parameter

Tags: java, apache-camel

I currently have the following route defined:

```
from("servlet:///my-api/v1/{param1}?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Map.class)
        .bean(myController, "myMethod(${in.headers.param1})")
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("application/xml"));
```

This does not work, when the message reaches myController.class, param1 is null.

Is there a way to capture the suffix on a requested URI and then pass it on as a parameter for a bean method?

I know you can do this if you use the restlet component but I would like to use servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, but it could be a nice addition to support. You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket: http://camel.apache.org/support.html

Today you would have to setup the route as

```
from("servlet:///my-api/v1/?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
```

and then grab the `Exchange.HTTP_PATH` header which should be the relative path, eg in your example `{param1}`.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for the confirmation, I'll see if I can log a ticket when I get a moment.